# X + Y gives HTMLObject (Select/option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add 2 sums, that are getting fetched by an select option.

All I want is to calculate X + Y, but i get a weird error.

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id1 = $("#one").val();
    $("#final_value").val(id1);

    var id2 = $("#two").val();
    $("#final_value").val(id2);

    $("#final_value").val(this + parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/957709/

Comment: `this` on your final line of code is casing the issue - remove it and you should be okay?

Comment: To do: Stop trying to “add” numbers onto `this` …

Comment: Why you try to like that "this + parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2)", why you wanna to add `this` to smth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `this` in your `#final_value` element. I've also added a `change` event to your code so it will update when one of the options change:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one, #two").on("change", () => {
        var id1 = $("#one").val();
        var id2 = $("#two").val();

        $("#final_value").val(parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <select class="full-width select2" name="" id="one" data-placeholder="" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="full-width select2" name="" id="two" data-placeholder="" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</td>
<label for="final_value">Result:</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="final_value">
```

Comment: Thank's! That was working! Thank you so much Gary. I wish you the best :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's a `this` in the last statement, replace the last line with:

```
$("#final_value").val(parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `this` value:

From:

`$("#final_value").val(this + parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));`

To:

`$("#final_value").val(parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));`

Cause if you will use `this` your function returns a string as:

`[object HTMLDocument]11`

Answer (score 2):

I have altered Gary Thomas Code little bit:

Instead of parseInt(), you can use like this:

```
var id1 = +$("#one").val();
var id2 = +$("#two").val();
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#one, #two").on("change", () => {
        var id1 = +$("#one").val();
        var id2 = +$("#two").val();
        var total = id1+id2;
        $("#final_value").val(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
    <select class="full-width select2" name="" id="one" data-placeholder="" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="full-width select2" name="" id="two" data-placeholder="" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</td>
<label for="final_value">Result:</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="final_value">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this keyword from your summation  as so :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var id1 = $("#one").val();
    $("#final_value").val(id1);

    var id2 = $("#two").val();
    $("#final_value").val(id2);

    $("#final_value").val(parseInt(id1) + parseInt(id2));    
});
```